# Ошибка: вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи

Tags: c++, память, инициализация

Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. `stack` было `nullptr`.
Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct Stack
{

    int* buffer; 
    int bufferSize;
    int top = NULL; 


};
struct  Queue
{
    int* buffer;
    int bufferSize;
    int head;
    int tail;
    Stack* st1;
    Stack* st2;
};
void Create(Stack* stack)
{
    stack->buffer = new int[20];
    stack->bufferSize = 8;
    stack->top = 0;
}
int main()
{
    Queue* queue = new Queue();
    Create(queue->st1);
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит ошибку на строке:

```
stack->buffer = new int[20];
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не инициализируете поля `Queue` при создании, так что в

```
Create(queue->st1);
```

`queue->st1` содержит мусор. Понятно, что при разыменовании для доступа к `stack->buffer` получаются неприятности...

Comment: То есть все функции в которых я пишу NameFunc (Stack* stack) изменить на NameFunc(queue->st1)?

Comment: @voitje каким образом Вы пришли к такому выводу? Вы попробовали выполнить код из моего ответа?

Answer (score 1):

В `queue->st1` - мусор.

```
...
queue->st1 = new Stack();
Create(queue->st1);
```